# Postgres add unique constraint

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to add a constraint to a table `x` which has many to one relation to other table. So the table `x` has field other_table_id.

There is other column in table `x` called `primary` which is boolean type.

I want to make sure that there is `none or only one primary=true` per one `other_table_id`.

Multiple rows can have `other_table_id` equals some same value and `primary=false` but only one `true` per `other_table_id`.

How do I create this constraint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a partial unique index for that:

```
create unique index idx_unique_other 
   on table_x (other_table_id)
   where primary;
```

This will only index rows where the value of `primary` column is `true`. And for those, the `other_table_id` has to be unique.